# docker: how to see which driver i'm using

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, curl

I'm new in the docker world.
I have a `Dockerfile` that emulates a linux machine and that i use to connect to a microsoft SQL.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN apt dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev openssl libkrb5-3 tdsodbc build-essential gcc curl coinor-cbc

RUN apt-get -y install python3.7 python3-pip python3-dev python3-tzlocal

# driver "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
RUN apt-get clean

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod -R 777 ./

EXPOSE 8080

CMD python3 app.py
```

with `RUN apt-get -y install tdsodbc` i install a driver called freeTDF (documentation https://www.freetds.org/)

while here i install the ODBC drivers

```
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
RUN apt-get clean
```

which drivers do I actually use? what I can write in the shell to check that?
thank you.

my problem is: I need to run an app (named app in the docker) that do a lot of queries. I need to have the chance to do concurrent queries on the same connection. meaning at least that if I open two connections on Database1 and on both connections i do one query the two can be evaluated at the same time and not the first one waiting for the end of the first (I'm in this situation right now and I don't know why)

thank you

EDIT:
i tried docker info on the shell. no information about  ODBC, SQL or microsoft are given. here the detail
[image]

Answer (score 0):

below command give you information about storage driver you are using.

```
docker info
```

Comment: hello, thanks for reaching me, I edited the output, but I don't see the specific driver I'm looking for. the strange thing (for me, that I never seen a docker before that moment in my life) is that I don't see a connection string. to the SQL that specifies which driver to use. but while on python I call the ODBC drivers, so I think I'm using them.

Comment: This answers the question as asked in the title. Thanks